# Screen is not full after deleting LaunchScreen from Info

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, launch-screen

I do not need in LaunchScreen, so I have deleted this line from myApp->Info in XCode. But after deleting those line my screen became:

[image]

It's not full screen. Do you see black parts? How can I fix it?

Comment: I do not set these images

Answer (score 2):

Add launch images for all screen sizes, that's how iOS determines supported device sizes.
Launch images are a good idea to give your user initial feedback instead of presenting a black screen - but if that's what you want, make a set of black images.

Comment: what about the StackOverflow iOS app? It doesn't have LaunchScreen

Comment: It does. It's a blue gradient

Comment: okay. Bit it has buttons and animation on LaunchScreen. Can I do it also on LaunchScreen? What about the segues?(I'm about Sign In buttons in the bottom). How can I do segues? LaunchScreen doesn't have controller file

Comment: The LaunchScreen is a set of pictures, there is no animation. Just after presenting the LaunchScreen in application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions you can continue with the same screen and add animations and interaction

Answer (score 0):

Simply Add Default-568h@2x.png splash screen & than try again.

It will work.

**Note:**

- There might be a question raised why we need to add a splash to resolve this issue ?
- Answer is because `UIView` takes size on basis of Splash screen you have added.

**Edit:**

- Default-568@2x.png is the Splash screen for App. That will appear when we launch application.
- Its default name for the iPhone 5 splash screen (because iPhone 5 screen resolution is 320x568 so Apple preferred it)
- Yes you need to add splash screens for all devices including iPhone 4, 5, 6, 6+ & iPad.
- To add splash screens for All devices:

Go to Targets -> General -> App Icons & Launch Images -> Click arrow on Launch Image Source.

See Image:
[image]

Than you will get this screen where you can add all Splash screens:
[image]

Comment: what is the Default-568@2x.png? Can you describe it? Is it some photo or? And why 568h? What if I run it on iPhone4 or iPhone6 Plus?

Comment: You should not use Default PNG anymore for LaunchScreens, use Xcassets instead. This will also give you benefits with iOS 9 and AppThining

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade: Have a look at HIG: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade check full answer